# postgresql not initializing cause of a parameter lc_monetary

Tags: postgresql

when trying to restart the service as a postgres user in the console i get the next output:

`FATAL: value not valid for the parameter 'lc_monetary': 'Spanish_Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela.1252'`

Please Help, regards.

Comment: Your question (and the code included) should be in English. Most users here are not able to understand what your fatal error even says and so won't be able to help. Additionally you aren't providing a lot of context, and a simple fatal error quote isn't going to be enough for a random person to pinpoint some issue in your system.

Comment: tryed to keep it simple because when write a lot of context the box says it does not meet the requirements and i have to start removing words in order to post

Comment: What operating system are you on? Since this is when you *restart*, what changed recently?

Comment: The problem was caused by another person and he fixed it himself, changed something in the setups, anyways thanks